# Personal data about purchases on Google Play Market

Tags: android

What personal data sees android developer in the developer console on the purchased application? may be mail, login, imei

Comment: Visit it.......http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/console.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the previous versions of the google play console, developers had access to all customer info except credit card number.

Basically, the developer was the main merchant end point handling all customer inquiries including cancelling and refunding orders, in the same manner as an online web shop. 
Customers would send an email requiring a refund, and the developer could easily find the order based on name or mail address.

This changed after some criticism over privacy concerns.

**In the current version, the play console hides all customer information except zip-code and country.**

All cancels and refunds are handled through unique order IDs, and the developers have to ask the customer to forward the order confirmation mail containing the order id.